# DBT- dbt depends on a source not found

Tags: postgresql, dbt

please help me resolve this problem: below are my source defined under *schema.yml* (along with two other models) -->

```
sources:
  - name: src_pizzas
    database: test_db
    schema: pizza
    tables:
      - name: src_sqlserver_pizzas
        columns:
          - name: size
            description: "The size of the pizza"
          - name: price
    .......
```

then I have this model under models/example directory as *tsnfrmed_sqlserver_pizzas.sql*  :

```
{{ config(materialized='view') }}

SELECT 
UPPER(size) AS size, 
UPPER(price) AS price, 
UPPER(pizza_id) AS pizza_id, 
UPPER(pizza_type_id) AS pizza_type_id 
FROM {{ source('src_pizzas', 'src_sqlserver_pizzas') }}
```

now when I run -->

```
dbt run --select "tsnfrmed_sqlserver_pizzas"
```

I get below error (table name and connection are all fine, as I have other models making connections, I cannot rule out typo type problems here):

```
Model 'model.pizza_data.tsnfrmed_sqlserver_pizzas' (models\example\tsnfrmed_sqlserver_pizzas.sql) depends on a source named 'pizza.src_sqlserver_pizzas' which was not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting answer to my own question. but the problem was human error, and others can face it as well. below are three things I was doing wrong caused the issue.

1. In the model's directory - I had no subdirectories and I was referencing all models to one single schema.yml file like below (I think dbt didn't like both sources and models mentioned in one single schema.yml file - I later created a separate subdirectory for sources and models and had separate schema.yml defined in them for sources and models.

   version: 2

   sources:

   - name: src_pizza
     database: test_db
     schema: pizza
     description: Source system schema description
     tables:

     - name: src_sqlserver_pizzas
       ......

   models:

   - name: transformed_pizzas
     description: DBT Transformed layer, all clumn upper case and date and time column added
     columns:

     - name: size
       .......
2. Indentation was causing issues as well in schema.yml
3. This is dumb but I was making my changes and running dbt test before dbt run. I was of the opinion (and wrong off course) that dbt should allow me to test it first and run it later. DBT runs test against views table, which are created as result of dbt run. so doing that in that order

Answer (score 0):

It appears there isn't a table named `src_sqlserver_pizzas` in that schema. You'll want to add an `identifier:` to the YML to specify the table name of the source.

```yaml
    tables:
      - name: src_sqlserver_pizzas
        identifier: "pizzas"
        columns:
```

Comment: thank you, i tried it, but didnt help, same error - would it help if i share - github link?

Comment: No, a github link will not help because this about what objects are named in your database. In my code above I'm assuming the table is named "pizzas". In other words, I'm assuming the table in the database is `pizza.pizzas`.

Comment: the database name is test_db and when i run a generate a select script in pgadmin , it ends with --> FROM pizza.src_sqlserver_pizzas

Comment: alison, i was able to find the cause of the problem and was able to rectify it. will post the solution here soon  :) but thank you for helping me